# Add WCF service to ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

We've got server-side application implemented in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1.0 that serves web application. Everything works perfectly but we were requested to provide WCF service for third-party client app.

I know that we could put WCF between app's logic and MVC's api. However, it seems like significant amount of work since the application isn't the smallest one.

I wonder if it's possible to build WCF service beside MVC and host it as one application on iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently not possible. The WCF app has to be a separate app.

Comment: Is this correct? In work we reference the `ServiceModel` namespace on Console Applications and create our WCF services that way, surely you'd be able to do the same in a Web App and write the `ServiceHost` in the apps entry point code.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you can do it if you use desktop clr

Comment: I'm just not sure if it can be done on .NET Core yet, unless the WebApp is a NET Framework app built on NET Core.

Comment: It will still not be the same webapp regardless if it's desktop or .net core. You might find a way to run it in the same process, but the base application model is different enough that you will have to run two separate http pipelines at best

Comment: There's no question about that, it'll certainly be running off two separate endpoint configurations. What I meant was that I'm not sure if you can use the `ServiceModel` namespace, and spin up WCF services, in NET Core as of yet

Comment: Some things can be done via SoapCore package https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore read more:  https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released an extension for visual studio which lets add service reference to asp.net core project. extension is called "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider"

Here is the link - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService

Answer (score 1):

From github:
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3139#issuecomment-417101129

> WCF service on .NET Core is not supported yet. The feature request is tracked by issue #2695.

Please upvote ;-)